# How to trim the new line character of column data in ctl file of SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, etl, sql-loader, ctl

My table data has contains new line character it is loading from sql loader ctl file, one column called 'IPADDRESS'is loading with new line character:

My ctl file :

```
 load data
 INFILE 'abc.txt'
 INTO TABLE TABLENAME
 APPEND
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\|'
 (MAKE,
 CUST_ID "UPPER(:CUST_ID)",
 IPADDRESS  "REGEXP_REPLACE(:IPADDRESS, '\\.\\D+', '', 1, 0)"
 )
```

Data in table storing is Ex:

```
Make CUST_ID        IPADDRESS 
------------------------------
C   MPG-VG-ALG01    "9.7.69.37
"
C   MPG-VG-ALG03    "9.7.69.39
"
```

Sample input  file data :

```
C|mpg-vg-alg01.gdl.mex.ibm.com|9.7.69.37 
C|mpg-vg-alg03.gdl.mex.ibm.com|9.7.69.39 
C|mpg-vg-alg04.gdl.mex.ibm.com|9.7.69.23
```

Comment: You can replace new line, or carriage return by replacing `CHAR(13)` or `CHAR(10)` eg: REPLACE(REPLACE('column value', CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')... or you could replace it in regex

Comment: This logic Not working

Comment: give me a sample of the input data please

Comment: C|mpg-vg-alg01.gdl.mex.ibm.com|9.7.69.37                            
    C|mpg-vg-alg03.gdl.mex.ibm.com|9.7.69.39
    C|mpg-vg-alg04.gdl.mex.ibm.com|9.7.69.23

Comment: @Rohan Büchner, I have  mentioned the sample file data in my question, edited..Please look into that

Comment: seems wrongly tagged SQL Server but should be Oracle

Answer (score 2):

Answer for my question is :   `column_name  "REPLACE(:column_name,CHR(13),'')";`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one option would be using `REPLACE()` function but need to add more;

- add `CHAR(data_length)` for string any data type even if it's of type `VARCHAR2`
- add **CHR(10)**(*line feed*) also along with **CHR(13)**(*carriage return*)
- don't forget to add `TRIM()` function nested within `REPLACE()` against extra
  issues too
- using the third argument is redundant

such as

```sql
column_name CHAR(4000) "REPLACE(TRIM(:column_name),CHR(13)||CHR(10))"'
```

moreover

```sql
column_name CHAR(4000) "TRANSLATE(TRIM(:column_name),CHR(13)||CHR(10),' ')"'
```

might be used as an alternative.